# If I use bcrypt() for my passwords, how SHOULD I use AJAX to verify them?

Tags: php, ajax, security, hash, bcrypt

Okay, so I finally understand how to use bcrypt() server-side with PHP... to hash and verify passwords. But how do I verify a password without transmitting the password to the server (i.e. client side verification).

Would it be safe to somehow send the stored hash to the client via AJAX and use a client-side version of bcrypt() verify to check the password against the hash? OR is the only way to verify the password by transmitting it to the server via AjAX? If the latter, how would I transmit it securely? If the former, where do I find a client-side version of the bcrypt() verify function?

Below is the PHP code I have for the bcrypt() hash class:

```
class Bcrypt {

    private $rounds;

    public function __construct($rounds = 12) {
        if (CRYPT_BLOWFISH != 1) {
            throw new Exception("bcrypt not supported in this installation. See http://php.net/crypt");
        }

        $this->rounds = $rounds;
    }

    public function hash($input) {
        $hash = crypt($input, $this->getSalt());

        if (strlen($hash) > 13) {
            return $hash;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public function verify($input, $existingHash) {
        $hash = crypt($input, $existingHash);
        return $hash === $existingHash;
    }

    private function getSalt() {
        $salt = sprintf('$2a$%02d$', $this->rounds);
        $bytes = $this->getRandomBytes(16);
        $salt .= $this->encodeBytes($bytes);
        return $salt;
    }

    private $randomState;

    private function getRandomBytes($count) {
        $bytes = '';

        if (function_exists('openssl_random_pseudo_bytes') && (strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3)) !== 'WIN')) { // OpenSSL slow on Win
            $bytes = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($count);
        }

        if ($bytes === '' && is_readable('/dev/urandom') && ($hRand = @fopen('/dev/urandom', 'rb')) !== FALSE) {
            $bytes = fread($hRand, $count);
            fclose($hRand);
        }

        if (strlen($bytes) < $count) {
            $bytes = '';

            if ($this->randomState === null) {
                $this->randomState = microtime();
                if (function_exists('getmypid')) {
                    $this->randomState .= getmypid();
                }
            }

            for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i += 16) {
                $this->randomState = md5(microtime() . $this->randomState);

                if (PHP_VERSION >= '5') {
                    $bytes .= md5($this->randomState, true);
                }
                else {
                    $bytes .= pack('H*', md5($this->randomState));
                }
            }

            $bytes = substr($bytes, 0, $count);
        }

        return $bytes;
    }

    private function encodeBytes($input) {
        // The following is code from the PHP Password Hashing Framework
        $itoa64 = './ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';

        $output = '';
        $i = 0;
        do {
            $c1 = ord($input[$i++]);
            $output .= $itoa64[$c1 >> 2];
            $c1 = ($c1 & 0x03) << 4;
            if ($i >= 16) {
                $output .= $itoa64[$c1];
                break;
            }

            $c2 = ord($input[$i++]);
            $c1 |= $c2 >> 4;
            $output .= $itoa64[$c1];
            $c1 = ($c2 & 0x0f) << 2;

            $c2 = ord($input[$i++]);
            $c1 |= $c2 >> 6;
            $output .= $itoa64[$c1];
            $output .= $itoa64[$c2 & 0x3f];
        } while (1);

        return $output;
    }
}
```

which is run via:

```
$bcrypt = new Bcrypt(10);

$hash = $bcrypt->hash('password');
$isGood = $bcrypt->verify('password', $hash); //verifies if the password is the same as the on that has been hashed
```

My question is a little long, but I really want to make my site secure. I'm using SSL, but I want to eliminate as many vulnerabilities as possible — and thus, I want to limit how much private data I transmit as much as possible. Especially user credentials.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't do that. If you did that, an attacker would be completely open to your hashing algorithm, and have access to the hashed password, and have access to the **result**.

No, ask your server to do the validation for you, and have it return `1` or `0` for success or fail.

Comment: The issue is, how do I securely send the password to be checked by the server then?

Comment: How do you prevent the password to be exposed in an ordinary form? You need to use SSL. Without it, all communication between server and client are exposed to an attack over an (for instance) insecure WiFi.

Comment: I will be using SSL... but I still shouldn't send the password in plain text... what should I use to encrypt and decrypt the password then?

Comment: @CharlesJohnThompsonIII: If you're using SSL, you have nothing to worry about.

Comment: then does it matter if I store the passwords in plain text, if I use ssl to login to mysql? /sarcasm/

Comment: Because if an attacker gets a hold on your database, you're giving him your passwords on a silver platter. SSL is good for securing server-client communication only. It is not an alternative for secure, high-quality code!

Comment: If "It is not an alternative for secure, high-quality code", then shouldn't I encrypt the passwords before sending them to the server?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't mean to come off as derogatory... I just want to know the best method for encryption and decryption if I am going to be transmitting passwords. SSL would be just one more layer of security.

Comment: @CharlesJohnThompsonIII: SSL does that for you. It encrypts the content of everything in the message. You don't need to encrypt it twice, SSL is definitely secure enough. What I mean by high-quality code is proper escaping of input, and not leaving server-side vulnerabilities.

Comment: Due to the recent controversy over the NSA allegedly paying RSA to use compromised/weaker encryption algorithms, I'm going to say that perhaps it is better to encrypt passwords client-side, there has to be a way to do it that doesn't rely solely on SSL.

Answer (score -1):

Dude, you have to store the passwords in an encrypted form in the database. In case an attacker manages to get access to your database he just has the hashes which don't help him very much if you use a good encryption. It's about user protection because moste people reuse the same password on many platforms.
This is the MAIN goal of password hashes.
Nearly every platform sends passwords in plain text (even Amazon etc.). The encryption is done in SSL.
You CAN of course encrypt passwords on the client side AND encrypt them on the server side, too (double encryption). But due to the fact that the the user has access to the encryption script logically (otherwiese he wouldn't be able to encrypt on client side) AND to the hash, which renders your client-side-encryption useless there is no cause to put so much effort into something which is not a big addition to the security.

SSL is just fine.

Comment: I am hashing passwords in the database, that's not what the question was. The question was simply in regards to transmitting the password to the database.

Comment: ALSO, RSA SSL certificates are not as secure as they are supposed to be based upon recent information about the NSA paying them to use weaker algorithms. So no, you cannot fully trust SSL. That is why I want to encrypt data BEFORE it is sent to the server.